# Anylogic Select OutputOut Block

Tags: service, output, anylogic

I'm preparing a supermarket simulation. My 8 cash registers work at different time intervals. If the cash register is closed, I don't want the customer to queue. How can I provide this?

[image: 1]

I tried creating a function. But I didn't know how to compare cashier work plans.

Comment: Pls share more details: the schedule setup, what you tried already... Make it easy for us :)

Comment: Each of my cashiers works at different time intervals. So I have 8 services.
I also defined 8 resourcepools and 8 schedule.. I mapped these schedules with resourcepools.

Now i want to do that 
If my cashier is not working in the calendar, I do not want to take customers to the relevant queue. 
If it will be clearer, I can share my project with you. I am doing this work for my master thesis. I have little time left. I would be grateful if you could help.